# Pesach Sheini and Karet

Tags: passover, halacha

On a related question [Jeremy noted](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1259/pesach-sheini-the-second-passover/1260#1260) that the punishment for failing to observe the positive command of bringing a Korban Pesach is Karet, spiritual excision. If one did not bring the Korban Pesach on Pesach for reasons beyond one's control, and subsequently failed to do so on Pesach Sheini for no good reason, is one chayiv karet? Is the punishment of spiritual excision applicable to Pesach Sheini?

Comment: Following the opinion of Rabbi in Pesachim 93ab, there is indeed a Punishment of Caret for Pesach Sheni, e.g. a convert who converted between Pesach and Pesach Sheni and intentionally didn't bring Pesach Sheni is Chayav Caret.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Rambam's Mishna Torah, Laws of Passover Offering](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/91.htm):

ה,ב  כיצד:  מי ששגג או נאנס ולא הקריב בראשון--אם הזיד ולא הקריב בשני, חייב כרת; ואם שגג או נאנס אף בשני, פטור.  הזיד ולא הקריב בראשון, הרי זה מקריב בשני; ואם לא הקריב בשני--אף על פי ששגג, הרי זה חייב כרת, שהרי לא הקריב קרבן ה' במועדו, והיה מזיד.

ה,ג  אבל מי שהיה טמא או בדרך רחוקה, ולא עשה את הראשון--אף על פי שהזיד בשני, אינו חייב כרת, שכבר נפטר בפסח ראשון, מן הכרת.  [ג] ומי שהיה בדרך רחוקה, ושחטו וזרקו עליו את הדם--אף על פי שבא לערב--לא הורצה, וחייב בפסח שני.

If you missed the first one **on purpose**, then if you miss the second one for any reason, you're in trouble (Karet).

If you missed the first one because of **distance or impurity**, you get a pass from Karet no matter what happens the second time around.  ("Distance" here is defined as being more than ~12 miles away from the Temple as of sunrise on the 14th -- Rambam 5:9.)

If you missed the first one for **any other reason**, then it's Karet only if you miss the second one on purpose.