# Why do we do anything for Pesach Sheini?

Tags: minhag, passover, calendar

According to my handy Luach, on Pesach Sheini, some people omit tachanun (I haven't looked into any source texts to see who does) and according to the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesach_Sheni) page, some eat matzah but I'm wondering about the nature of the day. Was there a sense of simcha for those people who were not observing Pesach Sheini through bringing a sacrifice in the time of the beit hamikdash? If not, why would anyone at all today mark the day in any way at all? And wouldn't those who "observe" it today through custom do so for 2 days because there would be the same concern over the date of Pesach Sheini outside of Israel as there would be for computing the date of Pesach itself!

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1259/why-is-there-pesach-sheini-the-second-passover http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16144/matza-on-14-iyar

Answer (score 2):

In his [Luach Hayom Yo](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/5761/jewish/Hayom-Yom-Iyar-14-Pesach-Sheini-29th-day-of-the-omer.htm)m, the Lubavitcher Rebbe explains the message of Pesach Sheini: "The theme of Pesach Sheini is that it is never too late. It is always possible to put things right. Even if one was tamei (ritually impure), or one was far away, and even in a case of *"lachem"*, when this (impurity etc.) was deliberate - nonetheless he can correct it." This idea that we always have a another chance to fix things is good cause for celebration.

See [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30483&st=&pgnum=277) regarding ommiting Tachanun on the 15 Iyar.

Comment: Does he mention this as a reason for celebrating nowadays or is that your application of his words?

Comment: @msh210 He doesn't specifically say that there.

Comment: @Michoel I like the point about not saying tachanun for both days but I don't know why it is such a shock that more people don't omit tachanun -- is there any reason for everyone to omit it on what amounts to be a private observance.

Comment: @Dan More people used to not omit tachanun. Then everyone decided to forget their customs and skip tachanun whenever they could. :(

Answer (score 2):

Megilas Taanis (perek 2) says that the 14th of Iyar, the day of the shechita of the Pesach, one does not make a hespid. It does not restrict this to those who are bringing the Pesach so it seems that it is a special day for everyone.

Comment: * __was__ a special day for everyone. Everything in that work was nullified except Purim and Chanukah.