# Besides eating matzah, what do we do on Pesach Sheini today?

Tags: minhag, passover, chabad

I had been under the impression that Pesach Sheini was only a historical and future observance -- that is, when the temple stood/stands.  I didn't make the connection that it might also be special *now* until somebody wished me an early Pesach Sheini samayach today.

I know that [some have the custom to eat matzah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16144/472) on this day and [some omit tachanun](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28208/472), and that Chabad [says it is a day of "second chances" and has some talks and essays on that theme](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/470865/jewish/Pesach-Sheni.htm), but I'm still at a loss for what one should be doing to mark the day.  It's not *chag*, but is there a custom to make a festive meal?  Are there any family/home-based observances (other than the matzah)?  What do those who do anything special on this day actually *do*?

Comment: The idea of pesach sheini is to help those who couldnt do it the first time because of tumah. It is rather an odd 'date' since for a woman who is tumah for the first will most likely be tuma also for the second.

Comment: As for [today (this year) specifically](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21407508#21407508)... ;P

Comment: Kind of the opposite side of the coin question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28063/why-do-we-do-anything-for-pesach-sheini

Answer (score 7):

Nitai Gavriel ([Pesach Vol 3 Chapter 57](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46449&st=&pgnum=330&hilite=)) brings several Pesach Sheni customs. Among them:

- To increase in Simcha (source: the Chida)
- To read the parsha of Pesach Sheni and learn its Halachos (source: The Shalo).
- To read the Parsha of the Nesi'im (source: The Shalo).
- To visit the grave of Rabbi Meir Baal HaNeis in Teveria (this is a sefardi custom sourced from many places). Some object to the festive nature of this practice.
- To visit the grave of Rabbi Yehuda Bar Illoi (a custom of residents of Tzefas).

He also mentions in a footnote that one of the objections Misnagdim had to the practices of Chassidim was making a meal on Pesach Sheni even if it was one of the days of [בה"ב](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%94%22%D7%91).