# Where is "no Tachanun" on Pessach Sheni documented?

Tags: halacha, minhag, sources-mekorot, tachanun

In almost every Siddur I have checked - as well as all the Luach's around, it says not to say Tachnun on Pessach Sheini - 14 Iyar.

Yet I cannot find a source for it, nor in Shulchan Aruch neither in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch.

Where is the source for this Minhag? After all, Pessach Sheini should be a sad day; we missed our final chance for this year to bring the Korban Pessach.

Comment: An anti-source would be the Pri Megodim:  פרי מגדים אורח חיים משבצות זהב סימן קלא   - 
 מה שכתב הפרי חדש סעיף ז' פסח שני י"ד באייר אין בו נפילת אפים, וכן כתב שיירי כנסת [ה]גדולה [הגב"י אות יב], אין מנהגינו כן. So one could claim that the הפרי חדש is a source.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28208/tachanun-on-pesach-sheni-sources-for-the-diffferent-customs

Comment: Why should "[Pesahh Sheni] be a sad day"? It gives those, who were previously tameh, another chance to offer the Qorban Pesahh thereby avoiding the punishment of Karet (Mishneh Torah, [Hilkhot Qorban Pesahh 5:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/9105n.htm)). That is a great cause for joy!

Comment: Having read your [most recent blog post](http://halocho.blogspot.co.il/2015/05/halocho-1572-today-is-pessach-sheni.html), I now understand why you think Pesahh Sheni is sad *in our generation* (i.e. without Beit HaMiqdash). Nevertheless, it's a very happy time, indeed a Hag for those participating, in the eyes of the Torah and the society it encourages us to build.

Comment: @Lee Isn't that a dupe?

Comment: Perhaps, though the prior one asks for sources for *and* against, while this one specifically asks for sources against.

Comment: @Lee I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: The [earlier question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28208/2091) asks for sources both in support of saying Tahhanun and also in support of not saying Tahhanun. This question only asks for sources in support of not saying Tahhanun. Therefore, partial answers to this question are relevant to the prior question, whereas partial answers to the prior question (e.g. an answer only including a source in support of saying Tahhanun) may have no relevance to this question. That's why I said "perhaps".

Comment: I think they should be merged, as this has generated a good answer by @Lee. (For some reason, the other Q didn't appear, no matter what I searched for before I asked the question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qitzur Shulhhan Arukh - Yalqut Yosef ([Orahh Hayim 131:36](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_7.html#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9FB%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%90B-B%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AAB%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AAB%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%95)) states:

> אלו הימים שאין אומרים בהם וידוי ונפילת אפים לא בשחרית ולא במנחה: חודש ניסן, **פסח שני**, ל''ג בעומר, מראש חודש סיון עד י''ב בו ועד בכלל, תשעה באב, ט''ו באב, ערב ראש השנה וערב יום הכפורים, מי''א תשרי עד ב' חשון. שמונת ימי החנוכה, ט''ו בשבט, י''ד וט''ו אדר א' ואדר ב'. וראשי חודשים.‏

Arukh HaShulhhan ([Orahh Hayim 131:12](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01582.html#HtmpReportNum0130_L2)) states:

> נהגו שלא ליפול על פניהם בחמישה עשר באב, ולא בחמישה עשר בשבט, ולא בראש חודש ולא במנחה שלפניו, ולא בחנוכה. ויש אומרים גם במנחה שלפניו, וכן נוהגין. ובפורים אין נופלים על פניהם, ובל''ג בעומר אין נופלים. וכן בערב יום הכיפורים, וכן בערב ראש השנה אפילו שחרית. 
>   ומנהג פשוט שלא ליפול על פניהם בכל חודש ניסן, ולא בתשעה באב, ולא בין יום הכיפורים לסוכות, ולא מתחילת ראש חודש סיון עד אחר שבועות. 
>   עד כאן לשונו. ויש מקומות שאין נופלין אחר שבועות שבעה ימים, מפני שיש לחגיגתו תשלומין כל שבעה (מגן אברהם סעיף קטן י''ח). 
>   **ופסח שני לא חשבו והוא פלא, ומנהג הספרדים שלא ליפול בו.**‏

While I would like to find a *harder* Ashkenazi source, it is *mashma'* from Arukh HaShulhhan that he supports *omitting* Tahhanun on Pesahh Sheni as saying Tahhanun on Pesahh Sheni would be "a wonder" (פלא).

Furthermore, Rav Yehezqel Ya'aqovson (Rosh [Yeshivat Sha'alvim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeshivat_Sha%27alvim)) suggests, in a [Devar Torah](https://www.shaalvim.org/yeshiva/torah/view.asp?id=422), that the Zohar HaQadosh ([BeHa'alotekha 153A](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01779_part_3.html#HtmpReportNum0008_L2)) intimates the joyous and propitious nature of Pesahh Sheni thereby serving as a potential source for the custom of omitting Tahhanun then. The Zohar HaMeturgam (Translated Zohar) states (my English translation):

> כֵּיוָן שֶׁכְּנֶסֶת יִשְׂרָאֵל מִתְעַטֶּרֶת בְּעַטְרוֹתֶיהָ בְּנִיסָן, לֹא מַעֲבִירָה כְתָרֶיהָ וְעַטְרוֹתֶיהָ מִמֶּנָּה שְׁלֹשִׁים יוֹם. וְכָל אוֹתָם שְׁלֹשִׁים יוֹם מִיּוֹם שֶׁיָּצְאוּ יִשְׂרָאֵל מִפֶּסַח, יוֹשֶׁבֶת הַמַּלְכָּה בְּעַטְרוֹתֶיהָ, וְכָל חֵילוֹתֶיהָ בְּחֶדְוָה. מִי שֶׁרוֹצֶה לִרְאוֹת אֶת הַמַּלְכָּה יוּכַל לִרְאוֹת. הַכָּרוֹז מַכְרִיז: כָּל מִי שֶׁלֹּא יָכוֹל לִרְאוֹת אֶת הַמַּלְכָּה, יָבֹא וְיִרְאֶה עַד שֶׁלֹּא יִנָּעֲלוּ הַשְּׁעָרִים. אֵימָתַי הַכָּרוּז מַכְרִיז? בְּאַרְבָּעָה עָשָׂר לַחֹדֶשׁ הַשֵּׁנִי, שֶׁהֲרֵי מִשָּׁם וְעַד שִׁבְעָה יָמִים הַשְּׁעָרִים פְּתוּחִים. מִכָּאן וָהָלְאָה יִנָּעֲלוּ הַשְּׁעָרִים. וְעַל זֶה פֶּסַח שֵׁנִי.‏
>
> As the Congregation of Israel is crowned in her crown during Nissan, she does not remove her crown nor tiara from herself for thirty days. And all of these thirty days, beginning with Israel's departure from Pesahh, the queen sits with her crown and all of her soldiers are delighted. Whoever wants to see the queen can do so. The announcer announces, 'Whoever was not able to see the queen shall come and see, so long as the gates are not locked.' When does the announcer announce? On the fourteenth of the second month, for from then and seven days onwards, the gates are open. From here and onwards, the gates are locked. And such is Pesahh Sheni.

Sha'are'i Teshuvah ([Orahh Hayim 131:19](http://www.mishnaberurayomi.org/pdf_pages/Chelek_2/0023_Siman_131_Seif_5-8a.pdf)), citing Shiyere'i Kenesset HaGedolah ([Note 12](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42559&st=&pgnum=39) in his comments on the Beit Yosef, Orahh Hayim 131), mentions that some have the custom to omit Tahhanun on the fourteen of Iyar:

> [...] אותן שנהגו שלא לומר בי״ד משום פסחא זעירא

HaRav Yehiel Avraham Zilber, in his Birur Halakhah ([Orahh Hayim 131](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_50537_120.pdf)), cites that the same is mentioned in Sha'are'i Efrayim ([Dine'i Qeri'at HaTorah, Sha'ar 10, Se'if 27](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_34320_310.pdf)). This is not so surprising, because [Sha'are'i Efrayim is the brother of Sha'are'i Teshuvah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephraim_Zalman_Margolis).

> יש מוסיפין ג"כ פסחא זעירא שהוא י״ד אייר

In a footnote to Sha'are'i Efrayim (Sha'are'i Hayim, see link above), this is also brought down as customary in the siddur Hemdat Yisra'el ([p. 76](http://www.seforimonline.org/unsorted/%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%AA%20%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%95%D7%99%D7%98%D7%90%D7%9C/Hemdat-Yisrael-3/0014.tif)) composed by [HaRav Shemu'el Wittal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Vital), son of HaRav Hayim Wittal.

Finally, Sha'arei Hayim (see link above) cites HaRav Hayim El'azar Shapira's Nimuqe'i Orahh Hayim ([Siman 131, Se'if 6](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7949&st=&pgnum=73)), who cites his own Sha'ar Yissakhar ([Ma'amar Pisehha Ze'ira, Note Alef](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4765&st=&pgnum=97)) who cites HaRav Menahhem 'Azaryah from Fano (a.k.a. HaRaM"'A MiPano) who writes in his Ma'amar Ma'ayan Ganim ([page 41](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7364&st=&pgnum=84)) on the topic of Sefirat Ha'Omer (my translation/emphasis):

> והנה יום א׳ של שבוע זה הוא פסח קטן **שיש בו מנהג קבוע לקצת קהלות שלא לומר תחנה ושלא להתענות בו** כי יום זה העיקר במצות הפסח השני.
>
> And behold, the first of this week (i.e. the fifth week of Sefirat Ha'Omer) is Pesahh Qattan, **which has an established custom in a small portion of communities to not say supplications and to not fast on it**, for this day is the basis for the mitzwah of the Second Pesahh.

Other than the custom brought by HaRav Shemu'el Wittal (above), which he writes was received as tradition all the way back from HaAR"I HaQadosh, Ma'amar Ma'ayan Ganim is the oldest written source I've found (dating back to 1620 at the latest).

Comment: OK - and what do the Ashkenazim use as a source?

Comment: Working on it. I just wanted to give you something in the meantime.

Comment: Shaarei Teshuva is probably why Ashkenazim don't say tachanun. He is printed with the Mishna Berurah.

Comment: It seems that in a year when b'hab falls on pesach sheni one still says slichos. One doesnt change the dates of b'hab.

Comment: TLDR: this is a minority opinion made up 350 years ago and popularized <250 years ago against traditional practice.

Comment: @cham That makes sense bc both behab and saying tachanun on 14 iyar are/were firmly entrenched ashkenazi traditions. only recently have people been forgetting about them.

Comment: I don't think you are reading the AhSh correctly. I think his wonderment is why the MA would mention the custom in some places of waiting extra days after Shavuot for not longer applicable Temple reasons, but not mention Pesach Sheni as well. He doesn't support skipping Tachanun on either of those days.

Comment: I've never learned Arukh HaShulhhan, so I could very well be misreading it. Nevertheless, do you have it on any authority that yours is indeed the reading? I can still see multiple readings, including yours, in his words.